# Why some pdf files are not recognized as pdf in android devices

Tags: php, android, pdf, http-headers

I am accessing this [URL](http://www.mdpi.com/2077-1444/5/3/814/pdf) with my android device and the pdf download starts downloading automatically, without asking me to open the pdf vieth the pdf viewer.

This works in other websites.

I am the developer of the website. I set up the header to application/pdf. Any idea what can be the problem? Thank you.

Comment: `Content-distribution: attachment` has long been a headache on Android. You'll find lots of posts and such about it through a Web search. I don't know what the current "state of the art" is, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I identified the problem and found the workaround.

It seems that the native android browser in not very intelligent. In fact, when a file is dowmloaded, the header of the file is not checked. The browser checks only the extension of the file in the url.

In my url, at the end we had /pdf, so no extension was found. By renaming the end of the url to xxx.pdf, the browser was able to recognize the file as a pdf.